# How do I stop my code from printing the extra question?

Tags: python

How do I stop from printing an extra input line? I'm new with python/coding

```
class1 = "Math"
class2 = "English"
class3 = "PE"
class4 = "Science"
class5 = "Art"


def get_input(className):
  classInput = raw_input("Enter the score you received for " + className + ": ")
  while int(classInput) >= 101 or int(classInput) <= -1:
    print "Needs to be in the range 0 to 100"
    classInput = raw_input("Enter the score you received for " + className + ": ")
  return int(classInput)


def get_letter_grade(grade):
  if grade >= 93:
    return"A"
  elif grade >= 90:
    return"A-"
  elif grade >= 87:
    return"B+"
  elif grade >= 83:
    return"B"
  elif grade >= 80:
    return"B-"
  elif grade >= 77:
    return"C+"
  elif grade >= 73:
    return"C"
  elif grade >= 70:
    return"C-"
  elif grade >= 67:
    return"D+"
  elif grade >= 63:
    return"D"
  elif grade >= 60:
    return"D-"
  else:
    return"F"

print "Your " + class1 + " score is " + str(get_input(class1)) + ", you got a " + 
get_letter_grade(get_input(class1))
```

Prints out:

```
Enter the score you received for Math:  85
Enter the score you received for Math:  85
Your Math score is 85, you got a B
```

Comment: You're calling `get_input` twice. If you call it once, it will only run once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your print, you call `get_input()` method twice:

```
print "Your " + class1 + " score is " + str(get_input(class1)) + ", you got a " + 
get_letter_grade(get_input(class1))
```

What you need to do is store your score by calling `get_input()` method once and use the stored value in print method:

```
score = get_input(class1)
print("Your " + class1 + " score is " + str(score) + ", you got a " +
      get_letter_grade(score))
```

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad I could help. Btw when an answer is useful for you, please consider upvoting or/and accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

I would separate out your calls to `get_input` from your print statement, not just here, but generally.

```
score = str(get_input(class1))
print "Your " + class1 + " score is " + score + ", you got a " + 
get_letter_grade(score)
```

As a rule of thumb, any user input should almost always be immediately stored in a variable to be manipulated and/or used later.